# How do I use regex to perform a validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'd like to evaluate a form field using a regex.

What expression do I use to actually compare the value to the regex?

I'm imagining something thus:

> ```
> if($('#someID').val() == /someregex/) {doSomething()}
> ```

But that doesn't work. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
if (/^someregex$/.test($('someID').value()) {
     // match
} else {
     // no match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is no `value()` method in jQuery, you need to use `val()` and [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) like this:

```
if($('#someID').val().match(/someregex/) {
  // success
}
```

**More Info:**

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

use the [**match**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method of the strings..

```
string.match(regexp)
```

so in your case

```
if( $('#someID').value().match(/someregex/) ) {doSomething()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
var myRegex = /someregex/;
if ( myRegex.test($('#someID').value()) ) {
    doSomething();
}
```

You can use [`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to check it and get an array of it's matches, or [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) from the string object.

Answer (score 0):

We don't *compare* values to regular expressions. We use regular expressions to *test* if a value matches a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
if (/myRegExp/.test($('#myID').val()) { 
  //... do whatever 
}
```

see 
http://www.evolt.org/regexp_in_javascript